# Почему возникает ошибка ValueError?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pickle

Я натренировал `Random Forest Classifier`. Сохранил модель, используя `pickle`. После, в другом `python`-файле, загрузил модель и передал ей предложение, которое ввёл.

Возникает ошибка:

> ValueError: X has 14 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 148409 features as input".

Вот формы данных:

```
train dataset features size: (23588, 148409)
train dataset label size: (23588,)
test dataset features size: (10110, 148409)
test dataset label size: (10110,)
```

Вот форма одного предложения:

```
text_test shape (15, 14)
```

Код в файле с постройкой модели:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
BoW_transformer = vectorizer.fit(data['Text'])
BoW_data = BoW_transformer.transform(data['Text'])
tf_idf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(BoW_data)
data_tf_idf = tf_idf_transformer.transform(BoW_data)
text_train, text_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(
    data_tf_idf, data['Label'], test_size=0.3
)
print(f"train dataset features size: {text_train.shape}")
print(f"train dataset label size: {label_train.shape}")
print(f"test dataset features size: {text_test.shape}")
print(f"test dataset label size: {label_test.shape}")
RF_classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
RF_classifier.fit(text_train, label_train)
predict_train = RF_classifier.predict(text_train)
predict_test = RF_classifier.predict(text_test)
```

Код в файле с входными данными:

```
import pickle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer, CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
BoW_transformer = vectorizer.fit(input_string)
BoW_data = BoW_transformer.transform(input_string)
tf_idf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(BoW_data)
data_tf_idf = tf_idf_transformer.transform(BoW_data)
text_test, label_test = train_test_split(
    data_tf_idf, test_size=1
)
print("text_test shape", text_test.shape)
with open("saved_model.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    RF_classifier = pickle.load(f)
predict_test = RF_classifier.predict(text_test)
```

Проблема, видимо, в том, что векторизатор имеет разные словари в разных файлах. Но как сделать иначе, я не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, проблема в разной подготовке фич. Фичи должны подготавливаться одинаково при тренировке модели и при получении предсказания, иначе вы получите если не ошибку, то просто какой-то бред при предсказании.

В общем, если вы используете какие-то трансформеры с внутренним состоянием и делаете им `fit` на данных, по которым тренируете модель, то вам нужно также сохранять эти трансформеры через `pickle` как и вашу модель, а когда делаете предсказание, то читать эти трансформеры из файла и делать ими уже только `transform`, без `fit`.

Кроме того, некоторые трансформеры имеют аналоги без внутреннего состояния, например, вместо `CountVectorizer` можно использовать `HashingVectorizer`, качество предсказаний возможно будет чуть хуже (а может быть и не будет), но при этом `HashingVectorizer` не хранит состояние и поэтому во-первых потребляет гораздо меньше памяти, а во-вторых его состояние не нужно сохранять и потом загружать (у него его просто нет), а нужно просто инициализировать его теми же аргументами при предсказании, что и при тренировке модели, и этого будет достаточно.